# Adding and removing call to handler from other classes

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-handler

I have a data that I always update every X time.

**MainFragment.java**

```
private void updateData() {
    if(updateRunnable == null) {
        updateRunnable = new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {                 
                callServerUpdate(); //fetching network data
            }
        };
    }
    if(updateRunnable == null) {
        MyApplication.getInstance().removeCallbacks(updateRunnable);
    }
    MyApplication.getInstance().postDelayed(updateRunnable, carData.getSeconds());
}
```

I'm using this method in my main class that, now in another class I have a trigger that should call to `callServerUpdate()`, I want to run `removeCallbacks()` also like I'm doing in `MainFragment.java` but I'm in other class. Do I have an option to call it from any place I want and to manage it so I dont have more the one waiting server call.